# Адаптивность блоков

Tags: html5, css3

Есть 3 блока, нужно сделать так, чтоб когда экран по ширине становился меньше, блоки соответственно так же становились меньше, сейчас же они перескакивают на следующую строку и как только остаются по одному в каждой строке, начинают сжиматься... Не понимаю, что я не так делаю

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgQPvp

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="div-wrap"><div class="div1"></div></div>
  <div class="div-wrap"><div class="div2"></div></div>
  <div class="div-wrap"><div class="div3"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: обнулите отступ для inline-block Например, родителю - font-size:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* width(или height) + border + padding = 100% */
}

.main-div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;  /* обнуляем отступ display: inline-block */
}

.div-wrap {
  width: 33.33333%;
  max-width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  /* по умолчанию значение baseline */
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;  /* устанавливаем нужный размер шрифта */
}
.div-wrap>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: где почитать про этот способ можно ? не совсем понимаю какой отступ мы обнуляли ?

Comment: http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html